# Trying to diagnose from this sound when accelerating

Tags: automatic-transmission

I have a '96 Holden Apollo, automatic, that has a point when accelerating where it sounds like its revving up a bit higher and seems like the gears might not be really gripping.

Thats my uneducated guess anyways. If I push the pedal a bit harder the sound goes away and it feels like I've got proper power at the feet.

Any ideas what this might be?

Answer (score 1):

I think it's time to visit the transmission shop. Every time I have had happen what you describe, something in the transmission had to be fixed.